# Does the soul of a child have relation to the souls of their parents? How does the pre-creation of souls impact the parent-child soul relation?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tanach, mysticism-kabbalah, soul

When parents have a child, is the soul of the child related to the soul of their parents? Some mystical teachings say that a soul is composed of multiple components. From this, I think that it might be possible that at least a portion of the parents' souls become replicated/transferred/imbued into the soul of the child. That being said, are there any discussions about this topic in different Jewish texts? Also if all of the souls are pre-created before they are connected to a physical-material body, how does this have an impact on the parent-child soul relation?

Comment: It's all very complicated, so I don't feel confident posting a full answer just now. Tanya Ch. 2 and sources and my Rav allow me to say this much: animal soul and garments of the Divine soul are produced, with Hashem, by the parents and is directly related. The Divine soul itself isn't necessarily related but will become permanently so through her association with the animal soul

Comment: The Gemara in Eruvin 70b says that a son is the extention of his father. The Rebbe in [Toras Menachem, Menachem Tzion, vol. 2, p. 558](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3240784/jewish/Chapter-3-Soul-Connection.htm) says that "The ties between two people, and certainly those between a husband and wife or between parents and children, are chiefly of a spiritual, not of a material, nature."

Comment: @Shmuel Thank you for the references. I knew that they had a spiritual connection, but I'm interested in a more detailed explanation for this question since I already took it for granted that there is some kind of a relation. I gave an example of the transfer/duplication of a component of one's soul from parent to child.